# debugging external js file functions in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an asp.net MVC 2 application. I have included an external js file like this:

```
 <script src="../../Content/custom-js/PhoneValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am trying to use its js function in my view, but function is not called. I have added debugger and alert statements in PhoneValidation.js but they are not called even.

I am calling the function from js file in my view like this:

```
   $("#btnCall").click(function () {  

var CallFromPhoneValue = $("#NumberCalledFrom").val();  
   var isValidCallTo = true;
                        var isValidCallFrom = true;
                        if (CallToPhoneValue != '') {                        
                            isValidCallTo = validatePhone('+ 33', '01456 7897654');
                            alert('isValidCallTo' + isValidCallTo);
                        }

    })
```

Please suggest how to debug external js file functions

Comment: Use chome debugger tool, https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: Do you get any errors in console?

Comment: @Dotnet Sparrow: Can you see whether the JS is loaded in the context or not?

Comment: i see the source code in view source and that file is listed at the top of html

Comment: If I get it right: 1) you call a validatePhone() function, which is stored in PhoneValidation.js. 2) You put alerts and `debugger;` in that function, but nothing happens. 3) You get no error in browser. Is that all true? If so, you must have another function called validatePhone, which is declared after you include PhoneValidation.js.

Comment: Yes that is correct. but i have only one definition of validatePhone which is in phonevalidatiion.js

Comment: 1) Are you sure that the browser goes into `$("#btnCall").click(function ()` ?  2) Are you sure that the `if (CallToPhoneValue != '')` is ok?

Comment: yes both functions are called. I just made some alert statements in  phonevalidation.js saw view source but source is not showing these new alerts even i hit F5 several times. second thing is that if i add  debugger in $("#btnCall").click(function (), it is not hit even it is inside same page

Comment: Try to call the function manually from console when your page is loaded, just type `validatePhone('+ 33', '01456 7897654');` in console and tell what is the result.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33179/discussion-between-kamil-t-and-dotnetsparrow)